# Разделение общей цены группы товаров на цены её составляющие

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Всем доброго времени суток!

Вопрос больше аналитический, чем сугубо "программерский".

Есть аукцион, есть лот(группа товаров), состоящая из N товаром в количестве M штук каждый.
Мы знаем начальную стоимость единицы товара.

В ходе торгов лот был выкуплен за сумму Х, которая никак не связана с начальными ценами товаров.

Сейчас встал вопрос, как выделить из цены X пересчитанные цены товаров за единицу, НДС и т.д. ?

В результате необходимо получить некую товарную накладную вида:

№_Наименование товара_Цена за единицу_Количество___НДС___Всего

1__товар 1_____________  12,34__________13___________32,08__192,50

.......

1__товар N_____________121,34__________3___________72,80__436,82

Итого:___________________________________________________ X рублей

Comment: Хм... А пропорции для "финансовой математики" работают?

Comment: @MBo вполне себе да. Вот только как быть, когда в результате перерасчета цена за 3 товара стала равной 11 рублей 11 копеек